# Other than Will Riker and Deanna Troi, have we seen on-screen any commanding officers on starships who are married?

Tags: star-trek

Starfleet has its own policies regarding fraternization between crew members, but I seem to recall reading that as long as the relationship was between people with the same rank, it would be fine. It also seems that there is some kind of stigma around Starfleet officers developing relationships with other crew members on board the ship. There have been captains with families living on planets, but not on board the same starship. Have we ever seen a case where a captain or commander is *married to another officer* and/or has a family on board?

Comment: Dax and Worf, possibly (married, Dax was commanding officer on the Defiant, but I'm not sure if both things were true at the same time).

Comment: I find it pretty hard to believe that with a crew of 1000 the Enterprise D did NOT have married couples on board especially since we know there are children on board.

Comment: @Paulie_D the question narrowed it down to "spouses or family of captains or commanders", which would be a much smaller group.

Comment: Benjamin Sisko did get some screen time.

Comment: In the TNG episode "All Good Things" it is revealed that there is at least one timeline where Jean-Luc Picard and Beverly Crusher got married at some point after the events of TNG, but AFAIK it's not clear whether that happend during or after them being on the Enterprise together.

Comment: Would Erin and Magnus Hansen count? I think I remember that they've disobeyed an order with their mission, making me think they might be starfleet personnel?

Comment: Kathryn Janeway was engaged to be married when *Voyager* began, but when she was presumed dead for years, her fiancé married someone else.

Comment: Honorable mention(?): Angela Martine and Robert Tomlinson in [TOS:Balance of Terror](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Balance_of_Terror_(episode)) were being married by Kirk in the Enterprise chapel when the ship goes red alert.

Comment: Interesting. So now they can't be promoted, or both must be promoted simultaneously.

Comment: Honorable mention to the Voyager episode Threshold where Captain Janeway and Lieutenant Paris settle down and have children. Okay, they turned into lizard like creatures first but it happened.

Comment: @DamionKeeling First of all, I think that "dishonorable mention" is much more appropriate considering the kind of episode it was. It pains me to think about it even now! Second, they never "settled down" because there was never the time or the opportunity. Was there someone bonding the two lizards in unholy matrimony? No.

Comment: "Starfleet has its own policies regarding fraternization between crew members" - do they? Is this mentioned or shown (especially in a somewhat consistent manner, rather than in an odd isolated remark randomly inserted by some scriptwriter)? "there is some kind of stigma around Starfleet officers developing relationships with other crew members on board the ship" - is there really? Except for some remarks made by various Captains over the years who felt they needed to maintain a professional distance to their crew, it didn't seem to me like relationships such as between Alyssa Ogawa and her ...

Comment: ... [Starfleet husband](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Andrew_Powell) on the same ship were anything unusual.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper We actually have a quote from Janeway suggesting the opposite: “Well, the couple in question might be urged to show a bit more discretion, but Starfleet has always been reluctant to regulate peoples' personal lives.” “Does Starfleet have policies regarding fraternisation” might make a good question on its own.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Perhaps you're right. I guess I got caught up in that time Harry slept with an alien.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On *Star Trek: Discovery*, Chief Medical Officer Hugh Culber is married to Chief Engineer Paul Stamets. Both positions command sections of the ship, and the CMO is responsible for assessing the fitness of command personnel for duty.

Comment: Additionally, Stamets and Culber (practically) adopt Adira.

Comment: @Xano That was some commitment to on-screen representation of queer family!

Answer (score 14):

When it comes to family members of any kind, on *Lower Decks*, Beckett Mariner is an Ensign on the USS Cerritos, the ship captained by her mother, Captain Carol Freeman.

The show explores the issues that this can cause and in the third season Freeman delegates her responsibility over Mariner to the XO Commander Ransom.

Going higher than Captain, *Lower Decks* also features Admiral Alonzo Freeman, Captain Freeman’s husband (and Mariner’s father). On at least one occasion (S2E10 “First First Contact”) he gives a mission briefing to Captain Freeman, so while they aren’t serving on the same ship they are (at least sometimes) within the same chain of command.

Answer (score 11):

We do have the case of [Beverly Crusher](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Beverly_Crusher) who was married to [Jack R. Crusher](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jack_R._Crusher).
Although the latter was killed before *Star Trek: The Next Generation* began (one event of the first episode "Encounter at Farpoint" was Picard returning Jack's body to Beverly), he made two more appearances, once as a hologram, and once in a vision experienced by Wesley.

Beverly Crusher has family on board, namely her son Wesley.

An alternate timeline in the ST:TNG episode "All Good Things" showed that Crusher and Jean-Luc Picard had gotten married and later divorced.  In *Star Trek:Picard*, Crusher and Picard had a son out of wedlock.

Comment: 'one event of the first episode "Encounter at Farpoint" was Picard returning Jack's body to Beverly' - this sounds a bit like the episode had included a scene showing that event, but it had happened a couple of years before the episode and was only mentioned in passing.

Answer (score 8):

Captain Robert April and Dr. Sarah April original captain and chief medical officer of the original Enterprise in the classic Star Trek universe. [image: tas robert april sarah april]

[image: tas robert april sarah april]

Balance of Terror almost had a successful wedding.

Answer (score 3):

Marriage is a tradition that could mean different things to different cultures. Some species "took mates". Others simply shared living spaces in an apparent common law type of arrangement. Others made the process legal according to whatever law the Federation or their government required. At the end of the day, these were just labels for committed relationships. So, yes, we did see those types of bonds between commanders and crewman. The most famous of these being Benjamin Sisko and his family aboard DS9.

[image]

But one of the elements baked into this franchise is the idea that devotion to Starfleet is kind of an all consuming thing when you command a Starship. Kirk overcomes a biochemical addiction to Elaan of Troyius because "the Enterprise infected" him long before she did. Picard breaks off his relationship with Nella Daren because he realizes his objectivity is compromised when he needs to send her into a dangerous situation. Janeway and Chakotay's *will they/won't they/they probably won't they* relationship that's only ever feasible outside of the confines of command. Even in Sisko's case, he ends up having to leave his family for what he perceives as a higher calling. Starfleet always ends up taking priority when you're in a command position, despite your best efforts to make it work. Or, you resign. Because it's easier to raise a family when you aren't being besieged by giant green space hands.

And, really, it doesn't *need* to be this way. It's just written that way.

Which is why I find it refreshing that they've steered clear of this trope with Burnham and Book. (And, really, all of nuTrek, such as with Troi and Riker still being together despite decades of adversity.) They still feel the depth of emotion when one or the other ends up in jeopardy or is believed dead. But this does not compromise their ability to do their job or assigned tasks. (Come to think of it, in a recent episode of nuTrek that will I not spoil here, this kind of bond even saves the day.) I actually prefer this kind of depiction. And their bond isn't any less a bond because they haven't made it a legal declaration.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some near-misses that help to elucidate the broader topic:

There were a few times when a captain lived another life as a different persona, and married: Kirk as Kirrok in “TOS: The Paradise Syndrome” (whose wife Miramanee died before he returned to his starship) and Picard as Kamin in “TNG: The Inner Light” (whose family was fictional).  We do not know how Starfleet would have handled that situation, had Miramanee survived along with Kirk, but since she was human, other episodes tell us the Prime Directive would not technically have applied.

When he was in his right mind and not acting under duress, James Kirk is serially monogamous, has been too professional to enter a relationship with his subordinates, and into blonde, human, female scientists.  (This must have been due to the influence of his father, George Samuel Kirk, because in the Kelvin timeline where his father died when he was born, Jim Kirk grew up to be much more like his reputation, sleeping with a green-skinned alien and sexually harassing Christine Chapel.) In his first appearance (“Where No Man Has Gone Before”) he reveals that he nearly married a blonde lab technician he was dating while in Starfleet Academy.  He has, in canon, at least *three* exes meeting that description: Ruth (whom someone impersonates in “Shore Leave”), Dr. Janet Wallace (“The Deadly Years”) and Dr. Carol Marcus (“The Wrath of Khan”).  All three say they left him because he and she were both too dedicated to their careers, and do not accuse him of cheating, but he seems to have kept looking for a replacement at that stage in his life.  At least one later ex of his, Dr. Janet Lester (a brunette), was serving in Starfleet at the same time as him.

In “Lessons,” Picard tells of his experience as Kamin to one of his subordinates on the ship, Lt. Cmdr. Nella Daren, and they have a romantic relationship, which is not forbidden.  However, they break up amicably by the end of the episode.  We later find out in season 3 of *Picard* that, a quarter-century earlier, Beverly Crusher became pregnant with Picard’s son while they were serving together, but left Starfleet and went no-contact with him.

Comment: Neither was married to another officer as specified in the question though.

Comment: @Philipp Okay. Added some information about other relationships between a captain and another officer that did not lead to marriage, but which I think shed light on romances between Starfleet captains and other officers.

Answer (score -1):

To add to the other examples, in Next Generation “Pen Pals” (s02e15), Wesley assigns a married couple to an away team, leading to an interesting exchange where a fellow officer mentions that he prefers to not have married couples on the same team.

> WESLEY: I have Prixus and Alans and Hildebrandt.
>
> DAVIES: It's a shame you didn't talk to me first. It's just personal opinion, but I like to break up married teams.

Comment: Note that the question asked about _commanding_ officers, though. According to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pen_Pals_(episode)), the officers mentioned in the quote were all ranked ensign or lower.